# How deal "connectedCallback may be called once your element is no longer connected" coding a Webcomponent

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element, native-web-component

That statement pasted in my question was copied from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks.

As a no-experience developer with Webcomponent, I am trying to understand all rule-of-thumbs and best practices recommended so far.

Continuing reading it says "... use Node.isConnected to make sure". It is quite obvious what it means: check if it is still connected but it is not clear, at least for me, what I should do to workaround it or what I should expect in some circustances.

My case is I am creating a Webcomponent to listen SSE (Server Sent Events). This will be usefull for a alife dashboard and several other scenarios. The SSE event will be basically responded either by NodeJs or Spring Webflux after consumed from Kafka Stream.

All simple examples I did so far I didn't face any issue with element not longer connected during connectedcallback.

Additionally, I didn't read any recommendation in [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/best-practices) regard "element no longer connected".

I read few excellent discussions:

[can-a-custom-elements-connectedcallback-be-called-more-than-once-before-disc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874212/can-a-custom-elements-connectedcallback-be-called-more-than-once-before-disc)

from where I learned that I can always trust in this lifecycle constructor --> connectedCallback --> disconnectedCallback.

And

[How to have a 'connectedCallback' for when all child custom elements have been connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663678/how-to-have-a-connectedcallback-for-when-all-child-custom-elements-have-been-c)

where basically I learned there is not a specific method "called after all children were upgraded"

Both questions pass close to my question but it doesn't answer me: which challenge or risk should be aware of or how to workaround the possibility to "connectedCallback may be called once your element is no longer connected"? In my scenario described above is there any treatment I am missing? Should I created some observer that triggers when the element is not longer available to recreate an eventsource object and add again a Listener to such eventsource object?

I pasted the code bellow for ilustration and the complete  Webcomponent example can be cloned from https://github.com/jimisdrpc/simplest-webcomponet and its backend from https://github.com/jimisdrpc/simplest-kafkaconsumer.

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `<input id="inputKafka"/> `;

class InputKafka extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {

    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))

    const inputKafka = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('inputKafka');

    var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:5000/kafka_sse');

    source.addEventListener('sendMsgFromKafka', function(e) {
      console.log('fromKafka');
      inputKafka.value = e.data;
    }, false);

  }
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldVal, newVal) {
    console.log('attributeChangedCallback');
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    console.log('disconnectedCallback');
  }

  adoptedCallback() {
    console.log('adoptedCallback');
  }
}

window.customElements.define("input-kafka", InputKafka);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only case when `connectedCallback()` is called after the Custom Element is disconnected is when you play with it: moving it or removing it very quickly after it is created could sometimes lead to this situation.

In your described use case, if you're using a persistent, single page application to host your Web Component, this will never happen. Actually your Custom Element will never be disconnected, until the page is closed.

Comment: You answered my question. Just an extra comment: In your opinion, is connectedCallback phase recommended to connect to a SSE service?

Comment: @JimC Yes it could. Connection is not time consuming so there's no side effect.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @supersharp has said I will add one other thing:

Do *not* call `attachShadow` in `connectedCallback`:

**Your code:**

```js
class InputKafka extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
    const inputKafka = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('inputKafka');

    const source = new EventSource('http://localhost:5000/kafka_sse');
    source.addEventListener('sendMsgFromKafka', function(e) {
      console.log('fromKafka');
      inputKafka.value = e.data;
    }, false);
  }
}
```

**Your code should call `attachShadow` in the constructor**

```js
class InputKafka extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
    const inputKafka = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('inputKafka');

    const source = new EventSource('http://localhost:5000/kafka_sse');
    source.addEventListener('sendMsgFromKafka', function(e) {
      console.log('fromKafka');
      inputKafka.value = e.data;
    }, false);
  }
}
```

Otherwise you will be attempting to create a new shadowRoot every time your component is attached to the body. *Yes, your code may not do that, but always write your code assuming that someone will attach, remove and re-attach.*

If you are not using shadowDOM then you will want to wait until `connectedCallback` is called to add your child elements as specified in the [Requirements for Custom Element Constructors](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-element-conformance).

I either create my child elements one time, if they are complex, or every time the component is connected, when a property changes or when an attribute changes.

Comment: "Your code should call attachShadow in the constructor" is clear to me. But I am wonder if I should consume a backend in the constructor and assign the response to an html object. Is "this.shadowRoot.getElementById('inputKafka')" really always returning true during constructor? I read to not "getElement" during constructor phanse. PS. I am struggling to figure out how properly unit test vanilla-webcomponents. I appreciate any clue to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908457/chrome-failed-to-maximize-during-unit-tests and mainly comment there if you would use wct for vanilla webcomponet

Comment: You could move the `source.addEventListener` into the `connectedCallback` but, it you do then you should remove the event listener in the `disconnectedCallback`. If you don't then every time the component is moved, assuming it ever is, you would add more event listeners and cause problems. The constructor can do anything to elements in the shadowRoot but it is not allowed to do anything to child elements that are NOT in its shadowRoot.