# Using connectedCallback() breaks the web component

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, native-web-component

I am learning web components and am building a dynamic list to get the hang of them. Having got it working, I read that it's best to attach the shadow root using the `connectedCallback` method. However, having tried to do this, I get a bunch of errors I can't fix.
Also, The way I am setting a simple attribute to a label seems a bit long winded: is there a simpler way just to pick up an attribute and display it as a label?

This is my working example:

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
<style>
    :host {
    display: block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    }

    button {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    }
</style>
<h1>To dos</h1>

<lable id="lable1"></lable>
<select></select>
`;

class TodoApp extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ 'mode': 'open' });
        this._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        this.$todoList = this._shadowRoot.querySelector('select'); 
        this.label1 = this._shadowRoot.getElementById('lable1')

    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ['att1'];
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
      this.label1.innerText = this.getAttribute('att1');
    }

    renderTodoList() {
        this.$todoList.innerHTML = '';

        this.todosArray.forEach((todoP) => {
            let $todoItem = document.createElement('option');
            $todoItem.text = todoP.text; 
            $todoItem.value = todoP.id; 
            this.$todoList.appendChild($todoItem);
        });
    }

    set todos(value) {
        this.todosArray = value;
        this.renderTodoList();
    }

}

window.customElements.define('to-do-app', TodoApp);
```

When I add a `connectedCallback()` method and create the shadow dom there, I get a bunch of errors.
My markup is just:

```
<to-do-app att1="value 1 attribute"></to-do-app>
```

I tried this:

```
class TodoApp extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    this.label1 = '';
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ 'mode': 'open' });
        this._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        this.$todoList = this._shadowRoot.querySelector('select'); 
        this.label1 = this._shadowRoot.getElementById('lable1')

    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ['att1'];
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
      this.label1.innerText = this.getAttribute('att1');
    }
```

But get the error:

> TypeError: can't assign to property "innerText" on "": not an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm [not sure at all it's best to define the Shadow DOM in `connectedCallback()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56908658/4600982) (unless you want to work with a Shadow DOM polyfill. Where did you read that?

Anyway, if your example with `connectedCallback()`, the error is due to the fact that `attributeChangedCallback()` is invoked before `connectedCallback()`.

That's why the property `this.label1` is not set yet when `attributeChangeCallback()` is called.

Instead, test the property existence:

```
attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if ( this.label1 )
        this.label1.innerText = this.getAttribute('att1');
}
```

And, when rendering the component, test the attribute existence:

```
connectedCallback() {
    //...
    this.label1 = this._shadowRoot.getElementById('lable1')
    if ( this.getAttribute( 'att1' ) )
        this.label1.innerText = this.getAttribute( 'att1' ) 
}
```

**Update**

The best way to read an attribute depends on when you need it. In your use case, bacause it is already in the markup when you need it in `connectedCallback()`, you can just get it by using `this.getAttribute()`.

Tu assign its value, maybe you should use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with variable instead of a `<template>` element.

```
let label = this.getAttribute( 'att1' )
this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<label>${label}</label>`
```

Comment: I read the advise here: https://dev.to/bennypowers/lets-build-web-components-part-3-vanilla-components-4on3

Comment: Got any ideas on my second question: what's the easiest way to read an attribute in the markup and assign it to a text label. It's not dynamic and only needs to be set once when the page is rendered. The way I have got it working seems a bit OTT for what I thought would be a simple operation. Thanks for the help above!